# IOS: Tab Bar Controller as root controller after login

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Storyboard and I have added the default `UITabViewController`, which has two `UIViewControllers`.

```
-FirstViewController
-SecondViewController
```

So the root arrow point to the tab bar controller in the Storyboard.

Now I have added a `LoginViewController` (that isn't a tab of the Tab Bar).

In the AppDelegate file, in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method if the user is yet authenticated, the application is going to show the first tab. Did I code it right?

Please look at the code below:

```
//inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
...
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);  
var tabController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as UITabBarController;

if(self.window != nil){
    self.window!.rootViewController = tabController;
}
```

The Tab Bar Controller doesn't have a custom class associated but the generic one. Did I take the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct for manually instantiating a storyboard as a root view controller. However, manually setting the rootViewController in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` isn't a great strategy. For one, you have to manually load the storyboard and then `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, which is inflexible and can break.

If you want to show a login screen first if the user is not logged in, try:

```
    if (checkUserNotLogedIn()) {
        //user not logged in        
        var loginViewController = CustomLoginViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Now your custom login controller is sitting on top of the tabBar.